# sharedModules into multiple completely different apps

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

I did the same thing he did here:
[How to correctly import the Angular Material module through a shared module in Angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44755692/how-to-correctly-import-the-angular-material-module-through-a-shared-module-in-a)

Except that I want to create an ui-kit like template then use it in different apps with different locations(they are not in same folder).

Currently, I'm doing that and everything works fine except when I try to use library inside my sharedComponent, like when I want to use :

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary">Click me!</button>
```

angular material button,

angular-cli doesn't throw any error , I just see this error on console:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError[ElementRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError[ElementRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ElementRef!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:993)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10878)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:12110)
    at resolveDep (core.js:12608)
BtnComponent.html:3 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read prop
```

and couldn't find anything useful by googling.

any tips can be helpful

**update:**

i have created a github repository that will reproduce error.

https://github.com/molikh/shared-module

i have wrote an issue with more explanation in angular material repository too :
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9294#event-1416171140

Comment: Are you importing `Mat`, and not `Md`? File structure, and how you import these things into corresponding modules will help.

Comment: What versions of angular and material are you using?

Comment: @RobinDijkhof, latest version, doesn't matter i'm building new app.

Comment: @Z.Bagley , i'm importing "import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';" . beside everything works when i use shared module in same app , but problem is when i use this sharedmodule in different other app and folder, even component works without importing material components , but when i use material components gives me that error

Comment: Well, this _could_ be a whole mess of different problems. Version issues for starters, wrong imports is another (`import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material';` is what it should be), and on top of that your **.module.ts** files could also be the issue. We'd need a lot more info to solve (versions on everything, written out module files, component and ts files correclated to the error wouldn't hurt either).

Comment: @Z.Bagley , question updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found one solution for my problem.

I build some libraries out of my components and then installed them inside my other apps.

Here is a complete tutorial about it :

https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e

Comment: Please add details on how you fixed the error I'm using the same tutorial and getting error in Angular 6

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I had not imported BrowserModule in my package module from which I was exporting the directive so all I did was to import it and add it to imports array

Like this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { myDirective } from './my.directive';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule
  ],
  declarations: [myDirective],
  exports: [myDirective],
})
export class ImageHelperModule { }
```

Comment: as far as I know there should be only one module with BroserModule imported in which is the main app.module. all other module that will be included in this module should import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common'  rather than BrowserModule.

Comment: but angular 6 have it's own library generator. did you tried that? ng generate library. https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4

Comment: I was exporting a sub module only that could be the reason.BTW I found multiple issues with packagr.I'll try using Angular library generator now

Answer (score 0):

I expressed the same same problem, when I tried to import module from sub-project which have its own node_modules directory. Building of the library into ./dist directory of "host" project and importing from there solves the issue.