# How to use Angular Material as core module

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to use Angular Material and follow the [Angular style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide)

After reviewing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46679456/10779873), the recommendation is to have Angular Material as a core module.

so knowing the following rules:

> Avoid importing the CoreModule anywhere except in the AppModule.
>
> A lazily loaded feature module that directly imports the CoreModule will make its own copy of services and likely have undesirable results.

*I wrote the following code:*

Material Module:

```
import { NgModule, Optional, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';

import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';

import { throwIfAlreadyLoaded } from '@demo/shared/guards';

const materialModules: any = [
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
]
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    materialModules
  ],
  exports: [
    materialModules
  ]
})
export class SharedMaterialModule {
  constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: SharedMaterialModule) {
    throwIfAlreadyLoaded(parentModule, 'SharedMaterialModule');
  }
}
```

App module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedMaterialModule } from '@demo/shared/material';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    SharedMaterialModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      [
        {
          path: 'auth',
          loadChildren: '@demo/shared/auth#AuthModule'
        }
      ],
      { initialNavigation: 'enabled' }
    ),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

lazy loaded auth module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
      CommonModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,

    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: LoginComponent
      }
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService],
  declarations: [LoginComponent]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

but the result after navigating to **/auth**, shows that the lazy loaded auth module doesn't know anything about Angular Material

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'mat-form-field' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="login.emit(loginForm.value)">
    <div class="container">
      [ERROR ->]<mat-form-field>
        <input
          matInput
"): ng:///AuthModule/LoginComponent.html@11:6
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a Shared Module which imports the Material module. On the other hand, any feature module that works with Material stuff, should import just a Shared Module. That's it.
However, in your case, your feature AuthModule doesn't have access to the AppModule and what it imports. In general, I create the Core module that is imported once in the root AppModule and nowhere else. Thus, Core module consists of services and singleton app-level components such as a navigation bar and so on.